# "missed from detection" or "missed to be detected"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, phrases, word-usage

I wrote a sentence like:

*The AAA signals are missed to be detected by the XXX device.*

Is it a correct sentence? Or the below one is a correct one:

*The AAA signals are missed from detection by the XXX device.*

Or both of them are correct?

Actually, I want to say that: the XXX device cannot able to detect the AAA signals.

The sentence format should be like the above one. Thanks.

Comment: The AAA signals are not detected by the XXX device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Miss from detection* and *miss to detect* are not idiomatic English.

You may use "fail to detect" in either active or passive voice:

> The signals fail to be detected by the device. —*This reports an inadequacy in the signal.*
>   The device fails to detect the signals. —*This reports an inadequacy in the device.*

However, if what you are reporting is not a failure but a success you want a different idiom:

> The signals avoid detection by the device.

But if all you "want to say" is that

> The device cannot detect the AAA signals *(Note that "cannot be able" is redundant)*

why don't you just say that?

Comment: thanks. one more question. "elements can be missed from the XXX set" -> is this a correct one?

Comment: @user1838343 It's marginally acceptable if what you mean is that some elements in the set can be overlooked, or if you mean that you regret the absence of those elements from the set; but I think it more likely that you mean that some elements are *missing* from the set--that is, they should be there but they aren't.

Comment: yes. I mean "some elements are/can be missing from the set". then, is the above sentence is correct? or is there any other word for *missing*?

Comment: @user1838343 You may say *missing from* or *absent from* or *not present in*, but not *missed from*.